# How to get p4merge like view with the ediff?

Tags: ediff

In the p4merge tool the layout for merging 2 files look like the following.

```
     +---------------+--------------+
     |               |              |
     |               |              |
     |               |              |
     |     a.txt     |  b.txt       |
     |               |              |
     |               |              |
     |               |              |
     +---------------+--------------+
     |   Choose any change          |
     |  from a.txt or b.txt and     |
     |  finally overwrite a.txt     |
     |                              |
     +------------------------------+
```

How to do this in emacs ?

Comment: Can you describe how ediff is different to that?

Comment: Ediff does not show the bottom buffer. It only shows the "a.txt" and "b.txt" files buffers that can be laid out horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the side-by-side layout of windows A and B:

```
(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-horizontally)
```

You may also want:

```
(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

If you're using `ediff` for a *merge* you'll get the third/bottom window C showing the chosen result.  This would happen automatically if the merge is being triggered by a version control operation, but you can use the `M-x ediff-merge` command to do so manually.

Note that in the manual case I think you'll also need to manually select the filename to write buffer C to (using the key sequence `w c`).  You can probably use the minibuffer history to select the filename with `M-p` or `<up>`.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i wanted to do. Does the hardcore emacs users use anyother mere package other that ediff. Just to make sure using the right tool.

Comment: `smerge` is the other popular option (also built-in).  It's fairly different in use to `ediff` (and I expect you'll like ediff better), but some people do prefer its approach.  They're both solid options, so AFAIK nobody has bothered to try to implement other alternatives.